# Is there a way to control whose news feeds my likes, comments, and photos I'm tagged in, appear on?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

There are some pages that I really like following, because I feel that they make quality posts, and I want to help them out by liking their posts. However, I do not wish my friends to see that I have liked their posts.

I understand that friends will be able to see the posts themselves and thus see that I have liked them; that's fine. I just don't want it to appear on my friend's news feeds.

This also applies to photos I'm tagged in, and posts that I comment on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any this kind of settings available as of now.

If your friends are following you then they will get notify on their news feed about your activity (Likes, comments) which is not set "Only me".

Tagging you can control by changing the settings of your [Timeline review](https://www.facebook.com/help/168229546579373).